# Magento 2 - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in the file vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Mapper/Sorting.php

Tags: magento-2.1, installation

I am getting this warning message when I go to store > configuration in the admin panel.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Mapper/Sorting.php

Posted my answer for the same. Need your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: I think issue is in following module app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml file.

Comment: did you face a similar issue and fixed it? The fix I answered is working but let me know if there is any other way to fix it.

Comment: Could you please do one thing? rename vendor folder and update composer once.

Comment: yes, I got the similar issue , My case there is extra space issue , It is resolved by formatting system.xml file.

Comment: Checked for tabs in the modules system.xml and removed them. It worked for me. Thanks.

@PramodKharade tried composer update but the same issue persists if I don't remove the tabs in system.xml.

Comment: What is Magento exact version you are using?

Comment: The current version is 2.1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to fix this issue.

1. Fixed it by changing the line 96 in this file vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Converter.php.

Actual Code: `if ($children->length && trim($child->nodeValue, "\n ") === '') {`

Corrected Code: `if ($children->length && trim($child->nodeValue, "\n\t ") === '') {`

2. Check if your XML file has any tab spacing within it. If so, remove the tab spacing and replace them with normal single spaces.